# Collection manager form solution

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, collections

I need to code a little collection management form one, in which one list box will show all available options from one collection and another would be one to which user would add selected items from all items collection or from which user would remove already added items.
Frankly this is not a much of a challenge at all but last time I wrote something like this I found my code to be cumbersome and convoluted. I was wondering if someone knows a tutorial on an efficient group management form since solution like this seems to be quite popular. Otherwise if you could share your preferred way of dealing with this. I do not need any code, only pointers like what collections you use and how do you deal with changes (what events on the collections you look for and how do you handle migration of object from one collection to another).

Comment: I'd like to see two or three use cases - can you provide us with some?

Comment: @Taw - sure, the most popular one is in your Computer Manager, Storage Management. When you create new spanned or RAID volume and you need to select physical disks on which to create the volume.